# Create triangular mesh of pentagon or higher

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, triangulation, delaunay

I have the coordinates of the corners of a pentagon

```
import math
import numpy as np

n_angles = 5
r = 1

angles = np.linspace(0, 2 * math.pi, n_angles, endpoint=False)
x = (r * np.cos(angles))
y = (r * np.sin(angles))
corners = np.array(list(zip(x, y)))
```

From these points I want to create a triangular mesh using [scipy.spatial.Delaunay](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay

tri = Delaunay(points=corners)

plt.triplot(corners[:,0], corners[:,1], tri.simplices)
plt.plot(corners[:,0], corners[:,1], 'o')
for corner in range(len(corners)):
    plt.annotate(text=f'{corner + 1}', xy=(corners[:,0][corner] + 0.05, corners[:,1][corner]))

plt.axis('equal')    
plt.show()
```

The result looks as follows:

[image]

Why are the simplices (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 4) missing and how can I add them?\

I think I need to specify `incremental=True` in `Delaunay()` and use [scipy.spatial.Delaunay.add_points](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.add_points.html) but this results in an error:

```
QhullError: QH6239 Qhull precision error: initial Delaunay input sites are cocircular or cospherical.  Use option 'Qz' for the Delaunay triangulation or Voronoi diagram of cocircular/cospherical points; it adds a point "at infinity".  Alternatively use option 'QJ' to joggle the input
```

Please advice

Comment: Delaunay means non-overlapping triangles.  Maybe you want to try networkx. E.g. `G = nx.complete_graph(5); nx.draw(G)`. [docs](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/index.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`scipy.spatial.Delaunay`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html) computes a triangular [tessellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessellation), meaning **non-overlapping** triangles.

You rather want all [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) of vertices.

Use the combination of "corners" indices as a source of triangles for [`triplot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.triplot.html).

```
from itertools import combinations

plt.triplot(corners[:,0], corners[:,1], list(combinations((range(len(corners))), r=3)))
```

Full code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import combinations

plt.triplot(corners[:,0], corners[:,1], list(combinations((range(len(corners))), r=3)))

plt.plot(corners[:,0], corners[:,1], 'o')
for corner in range(len(corners)):
    plt.annotate(text=f'{corner + 1}', xy=(corners[:,0][corner] + 0.05, corners[:,1][corner]))

plt.axis('equal')    
plt.show()
```

Alternatively, skip the `triplot` and use a [`LineCollection`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.LineCollection) from a `combination` of **pairs** of points:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import collections  as mc

ax = plt.subplot()
plt.plot(corners[:,0], corners[:,1], 'o')
lines = mc.LineCollection(combinations(corners, r=2))
ax.add_collection(lines)

for corner in range(len(corners)):
    plt.annotate(text=f'{corner + 1}', xy=(corners[:,0][corner] + 0.05, corners[:,1][corner]))

plt.axis('equal')    
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]